# Maven "install site-deploy deploy" - does it run phases twice?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-site-plugin

Let's say I run Maven with

```
install site-deploy deploy
```

(The reason: I only want to deploy if both the artifact and the site can be built.)

Will Maven run all the phases up to `install` *again* when I call `deploy`? Or is it smart enough to see that there has already been a successful `install` in the same Maven call?

If not: What can I do to "tell" Maven to not repeat itself? Do I need to list the goals separately?

Comment: You could just call it, and watch, and you'd have your answer.  So, why haven't you?

Comment: It might or might not depend on the used plugins, project type etc. Maybe I should have made some tests, but that does not necessarily tell me how it's meant to be.

Comment: Based on the life cycle the install phase will run a second time if you use `deploy` cause it's part of the life cycle...What about using `mvn deploy site-deploy`?

Comment: @khmarbaise The problem with "mvn deploy site-deploy" is that if building the site fails (which actually happens sometimes - e.g. some dependencyManagement entries allow you to build, but break if you call site), the deployment has already happened. The build server shows you a failed build, but actually you have an artifact in Nexus which just lacks a site.

Comment: Hm..why can some dependencyManagement entries break a site ?

Comment: I recently had a case where a dependencymanagement entry without a version lead to an error in site but not in    package.

Comment: I do not claim that such entry is useful but this was a real problem of a real developer.